# Docker Swarm with image versions externalized to .env file

Tags: docker, docker-swarm-mode, docker-stack

I used to externalized my image versions to my .env file. This make it easy to maintain and I don't modify my `docker-compose.yml` file just to upgrade a version, so I'm sure I won't delete a line by mistake or whatever.

But when I try to deploy my services with `stack` to the `swarm`, docker engine complains that my image is not a correct reposity/tag, with the exact following message :

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = ContainerSpec: "GROUP/IMAGE:" is not a valid repository/tag

To fix this, I can fix the image version directly in the `docker-compose.yml` file. Is there any logic here or it that a bug? But this mixes fix part of the docker-compose and variable ones.

Cheers,
Olivier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned the `.env` isn't currently supported by the `docker stack`.
So the alternative way is to clearly specify the environment file using by `env_file`, e.g.:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  foo-service:
    image: foo-image
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      - SOME_ENV=qwerty
```

Comment: Does it support variable substitution in the `.env` file, e.g. `PGDATABASE=${DATABASE_HOST}` when used like this?

Comment: I just tried it out with a small example and the answer is no :(

Comment: @RogerCollins, what is docker version do you have? What is a version of a docker-compose file? How looks like your .env file? Please, provide more details

Comment: @xxxception docker versions >18.09 - `docker stack` does not support env_file.  See the issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133

Comment: You are confusing .env (used in the docker-compose template itself) and env_file (passed into the containers)

Answer (score 26):

The yaml parser in `docker stack deploy` doesn't have all the same features of that in `docker-compose`. However, you can use `docker-compose config` to output a yaml file after it's done all the variable substitutions, extending other files, and merging multiple files together. This effectively turns `docker-compose` into a preprocessor.

Comment: Hi @bmitch. I know `docker stack deploy` does not have all features that `docker-compose` has. That what I wrote below in my own answer, with a link to the relative issue in GitHub. By the way, I didn't know we can use `docker-compose` as a preprocessor. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks! I use a script deploy.sh that is simple and it just works:

   `#!/usr/bin/env bash
   docker-compose config > docker-compose-parsed.yaml
   docker stack deploy -c ./docker-compose-parsed.yaml MY_SERVICE `

Comment: This should be the accepted answer -- use this in conjunction with `docker stack deploy -c -` which reads from stdin, so you have `docker-compose config | docker stack deploy -c -`

Answer (score 9):

The answer is quite simple: it's not a bug, nor a feature. `.env` is not currently supported by `docker stack`.
You must source manually the `.env` running `export $(cat .env)` before running `docker stack ...`

There is an issue discussing this needs in the Docker Github.
https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3654
and another one discussing the problem and solution: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29133#issuecomment-285980447

Answer (score 7):

you can create a `deploy.sh`

```sh
export $(cat .env) > /dev/null 2>&1; docker stack deploy ${1:-STACK_NAME}
```

- The `.env` parses without regular expressions or unstable tricks.
- Errors on `stderr` produced by `#comments` inside the `.env` will be redirected to `stdin` (2>&1)
- Undesired prints of all `export` and `error` now on `stdin` too, are redirected to `/dev/null`. This prevents console flood.
- Those errors do not prevent `.env` being parsed correctly.

We can define `STACK_NAME` in our `.env` but we can also pass our customized `stack_name`

```sh
. deploy.sh <stack_name> (stack_name opcional)
```

This workaround gave me headaches for 3 nights

Comment: This is what worked for me, simple solution to inject the .env content.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue,
My issue was caused by running docker-compose in a different python virtual environment.

I hope this could help.

It seems that by running on a different python virtual env, I ruined the docker-compose dependency pythondotenv